# Calculating covariance, with multiplication by stochastic variable.

Tags: stochastic-calculus

As an exercise I'm supposed to calculate; $\text{cov}(X \cdot Y,X)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent discrete stochastic variables, with probability functions given by;
$$
p\left(var\right) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0.1 & \text{ if } var = 0 \\
0.4 & \text{ if } var = 1 \\
0.5 & \text{ if } var = 2 \\
0   & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
However I'm unable to find a rule, which applies to this case. (That is covariance, with multiplication by stochastic varibles).

I've tried to substitute $X \cdot Y$, with a new stochastic variable $Z = X \cdot Y$, with $p_{Z}\left(z\right) = p_{X}\left(z\right) \cdot p_{Y}\left(y\right)$, however this does not seem to result in the correct answer.

So I'd love to get a pointer, on how to proceed.

The answer is supposed to be $0.616$, $EX = 1.4$, $Var\left(X\right) = 0.44$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

1. $cov(X,Y)=E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$
2. For independent variables $E[AB]=E[A]E[B]$
3. $var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$

So $cov(XY,X) =E[X^2Y]-E[XY]E[X]=(E[X^2]-E[X]^2)E[Y]=var(X)E[Y]=0.44*1.4=0.616$

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $Y$ independent of $Z$ and $X$.  We can write $\mathrm{Cov}(X,YZ)=E[Y] \;\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z)$.  Here $Z=X$.